# Generate an alert/pop up if mail not received

Tags: windows, email

Everyday I have to receive an email from a specific address in 30 mins intervals.

Is there any way for Outlook (or whatever) to get an alert if these mails have stopped coming in?

Comment: You can filter your messages in Outlook by going to `More Mail Settings > Rules for Sorting new Messages > New`. You could then send an alert to your mobile phone as soon as a message was received. As soon as you stopped getting them, that *would* warn you. (It isn't what you expected to find, but it's a feasible answer, as e-mail wasn't made with the intent of waiting for it to appear)

Answer (score 0):

- Setup an Outlook rule catching your special mails and performing action of running an application.
- Find a good [free timer application](http://lifehacker.com/5747056/five-best-windows-timer-applications) in internet that you could add and remove (or reset) alarms by command line.
- Create a rule catching your special mail and having an action of running application.
- Write a VBS script that you will use as this application. The script's content would be something like this:

  ```
  Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  oShell.run "YourTimer.exe delete-last-timer", 0, false
  oShell.run "YourTimer.exe setup-new-30min-timer", 0, false
  ```

  where **YourTimer.exe** is the good free timer application, **delete-last-timer** and **setup-new-30min-timer** are options to perform such actions and **0** parameter means run YourTimer.exe hidden. Use **1** if you want to run it normally.

Then each new email will restart 30-min interval and if no email would come, then timer will get to action and produce sounds, popups, may be play music or run any other applications of your choice, etc.